# Image inside a div

Tags: html, css

I can't align an image inside a div.
I want to align it to the right.

After set the image float to right I get this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/pNzY56Y.png]

```
<img src="Images/Products/47_dolcimo-max-001.jpg" width="263" height="155" style="float:right;">
```

It's looks like off the div, which it isn't.

And if I set the float to none which is the same as nothing, I get it inside and at the right of the div. At least visualy.
[image]

```
<img src="Images/Products/47_dolcimo-max-001.jpg" width="263" height="155" style="float:none;">
```

CSS from the div:

```
.headerphoto {
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 760px;
    height: 100%;
    border-width:1px;       
    border-color:#EFEDED;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

HTML from the div:

```
<div class="headerphoto">

    <img src="Images/Products/practidose.fw.png" width="760" height="65" > 
    <img src="Images/Products/47_dolcimo-max-001.jpg" width="263" height="155" style="float:none;"> 

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want to align it to the right, and then you show us an image of it aligned to the right and you say that isn't what you want.

Comment: So in what way you want the image, use paint and brush to explain .. plz

Comment: @TylerH Yes I want it to the right. The problem is that the image seems to be off the div visualy, and that is the problem. It should be inside the div.

Comment: your complete html please.

Comment: Off the div doesn't mean anything. Your div has no real content or borders, so there's no way for us to know what is "on" or "off" the div (the actual way to say this is "inside" or "outside" of the div, by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image appears outside of your div because you are not clearing the float.  There is a number of ways you can do this.  I reccomend adding `overflow: hidden` to your parent div

```
.headerphoto {
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 760px;
    height: 100%;
    border-width:1px;       
    border-color:#EFEDED;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    margin-top:20px;
    overflow: hidden; /* ADDED THIS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make it a background image instead ..

```
<div style="background-image:url(path/to/img.png);background-position: center right; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
</div>
```

set your (min-)? height of the div to the height of your image.

Answer (score 0):

When you `float` element it is taken out of document flow. This means parent `div` does not see it and that's why your image looks like outside of div. What you need to do is to clear floats.

More here:
http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

After floated element:
    .clear { clear: both;display: block;overflow: hidden;visibility: hidden;width: 0;height: 0;  }

Or on floated element yo add `clearfix` class:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use floats in a case like this but if you do want to use floats and keep it inside the containing div then you have to set the bottom image to float right and then just add a height to your container with CSS, the height from top of the first image to the bottom of the second image.

Answer (score -1):

img tag has display: inline; value by default. Just add another tag and add text-align: right;

```
<div class="img_wrapper">
<img src="path_to_img" />
</div>

<style>.img_wrapper {
    text-align:right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: But that will afect the text that I also will insert. The image and the text would be align to the right. I just want the image, not the text.